# Send queries to R server programmatically

Tags: r, svsocket

Please consider the following example (using 2 R sessions):

## 1st R session - R Server

```
library(svSocket)
startSocketServer()
```

## 2nd R session - R Client

```
library(svSocket)
con <- socketConnection(host = "localhost", port = 8888, blocking = FALSE)

value<-"setosa"
evalServer(con, tmp, value) # first call to the server
evalServer(con, head(iris[iris$Species==tmp,])) # second call to the server
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

To send the above query I need a 2-step process where I first save my parameter in the server and then I use them to query the table.

## Problem

Do the same in one step only. For example, building the query using `paste` and send it to the server like I would in PHP + MySQL. Basically, I need to avoid that a different user overwrites `tmp` between the first and the second call to the server. The above commands will be running behind web apps with 30 to 50 users simultaneously connected, so I reckon that this inconvenience might happen.

Comment: Take look at [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/). There's also a [php library](https://github.com/cturbelin/rserve-php) for it. I think it will (heh) serve you better than the `svSocket' approach as it was really intended as a GUI back-end connection. Also, since you're familiar with R, why not just use Shiny?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I already have a rApache implementation. I have simply no time to switch to a different technology. I chose this because it makes R behave like PHP and others, which means people can start to see R as a general purpose language... something I'd really love to happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible answer

```
$ query <- paste0('evalServer(con,"head(iris[iris$Species==\'', value,'\',])")')
$ eval(parse(text=query))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

This does the job but it's kind of a dial... The code is very messy and difficult to read.

## Final solution:

I ended up modifying/simplifying `evalServer`. This version accept only a character string with the expression to evaluate in the server

```
evalServer2 <- function (con, expr) 
{
  if(!is.character(expr)) stop("expr must be a character string containing the expression to evaluate in the server.")
  cat("..Last.value <- try(eval(parse(text = \"", expr, "\"))); .f <- file(); dump(\"..Last.value\", file = .f); flush(.f); seek(.f, 0); cat(\"\\n<<<startflag>>>\", gsub(\"<pointer: [0-9a-fx]+>\", \"NULL\", readLines(.f)), \"<<<endflag>>>\\n\", sep = \"\\n\"); close(.f); rm(.f, ..Last.value); flush.console()\n", 
      file = con, sep = "")
  objdump <- ""
  endloc <- NULL
  while (!length(endloc)) {
    obj <- readLines(con, n = 1000, warn = FALSE)
    if (!length(obj)) {
      Sys.sleep(0.01)
      next
    }
    endloc <- grep("<<<endflag>>>", obj)
    if (length(endloc)) 
      obj <- obj[0:(endloc[length(endloc)] - 1)]
    objdump <- c(objdump, obj)
  }
  startloc <- grep("<<<startflag>>>", objdump)
  if (!length(startloc)) 
    stop("Unable to find <<<startflag>>>")
  objdump <- objdump[-(1:startloc[length(startloc)])]
  nospace <- grep("[^ ]$", objdump)
  nospace <- nospace[nospace < length(objdump)]
  for (i in rev(nospace)) {
    objdump[i] <- paste(objdump[i], objdump[i + 1], sep = "")
    objdump[i + 1] <- ""
  }
  objcon <- textConnection(objdump)
  on.exit(close(objcon))
  source(objcon, local = TRUE, echo = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)
  return(..Last.value)
}
```

which allows:

```
> x <- "5 + 4"
> evalServer2(con, x)
[1] 9
```

Instead, `evalServer` would retrieve a variable called `x` stored in the R server

```
> evalServer(con, x, 23)
[1] TRUE
> evalServer(con, x)
[1] 23
> evalServer2(con, "x")
[1] 23
```